# AWS S3 cp not showing progress output to console [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Node.js server where I'm handling AWS S3 uploads. My spawn code looks like this:

```
const command = `aws s3 --region us-west-2 cp ${filePath} ${s3Path} --recursive`;

const subprocess = spawn(command, {
    stdio: 'pipe',
    shell: true
});

subprocess.stdio[2].on('data', data => {
    const ss = data.toString('utf-8');
    logger.info(ss); //I have a logger
});
```

The issue is AWS is not returning any data to the `stdout` data event. After looking at the docs for S3 `cp`, I thought I might have been suppressing the logs but I'm not. Does anyone know what's happening?

==============

**UPDATE 1**

I manually typed my command into the command prompt and I'm seeing the progress output I need. Still not sure why Node.js isn't picking up on it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, though I don't understand why it happens so any input on this would be great.

According to the node.js docs `subprocess.stdio` is an array with (by default) 3 pipes: `subprocess.stdin`, `subprocess.stdout`, and `subprocess.stderr`. Naturally, they carry the indices 0 - 2, respectively. My issue was that I was pointing to the wrong index, so instead of doing `subprocess.stdio[2]` (representing the standard error), I needed to do `subprocess.stdio[1]` (representing the standard output). Now the AWS output is displaying on the console.

The reason I didn't catch on is because I'm using ffmpeg with the same code (which executes first) and it uses index 2 for some reason. This is the part that confuses me.